# Azure blob: how many read/write operations?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I do not understand how to find out my stats on azure blob storage. Egress and ingress show data in volume, not in reads/writes and I do not think this is necessarily data operations, because there is no way something is downloading 20 gigs of data a day from the blob storage (shows this much egress). Pricing, on the other hand, is all read-write operations.

I want to find out the usage statistics on my blob storage so I could adapt the storage strategy, put the relevant stuff in hot/cold storage, archive things appropriately. I need practical data for analysis.

The metrics in portal are mostly error counts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Azure Storage Analytics provides more detailed metrics (aggregated per minute and hour) about all services (e.g. Blob, File, Table and Queue) in the storage account usage, such as:

- user;GetBlob -> TotalRequests, TotalBillableRequests, TotalIngress, TotalEgress, Availability, etc.;

Find more details at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-analytics.